# How to interrupt BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, blocking, interrupt

BlockingQueue.put can throw InterruptedException.
How can I cause the queue to be interrupting by throwing this exception?

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Param> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Param>(NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS);
...
try {
    queue.put(param);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "put Interrupted", e);
}
...
// how can I queue.notify?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to interrupt the thread that is calling the `queue.put(...);`.  The `put(...);` call is doing a `wait()` on some internal condition and if the thread which is calling the `put(...)` gets interrupted, the `wait(...)` call will throw `InterruptedException` which is passed on by the `put(...);`

```
// interrupt a thread which causes the put() to throw
thread.interrupt();
```

To get the thread you can either store it when it is created:

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
...
workerThread.interrupt();
```

or you can use the `Thread.currentThread()` method call and store it somewhere for others to use to interrupt.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     public Thread myThread;
     public void run() {
         myThread = Thread.currentThread();
         ...
     }
     public void interruptMe() {
         myThread.interrupt();
     }
}
```

Lastly, it is a good pattern when you catch `InterruptedException` to immediately re-interrupt the thread because when the `InterruptedException` is thrown, the interrupt status on the thread is cleared.

```
try {
    queue.put(param);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // immediately re-interrupt the thread
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    Log.w(TAG, "put Interrupted", e);
    // maybe we should stop the thread here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `put` will wait for a slot to be free before it adds the `param` and flow can continue.

If you capture the thread that is running when `put` is called (ie, call `Thread t1 = Thread.currentThread()` before calling `put`) and then in another thread call `interrupt` on this (whilst the `t1` is blocked).

[This example](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/threading/wakeup/) has something similar whereby it takes care of calling interrupt after a given timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a reference to the thread running the code with queue.put(), like in this test

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
            try {
                queue.put(new Object());
                queue.put(new Object());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    };
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    t.interrupt();
```